# LaTex Sketch Help needed?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I am using Ti*k*z to draw a figure that compromises a lot of things I will certainly need for further figures. It would be great if someone would help out! I am currently stuck and especially when it comes to the block positioning...

[image: tikz sketch]

Here's what I have thus far, but I need some arrow text:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [block/.style={draw,minimum width=#1,minimum height=2em},
        block/.default=10em,high/.style={minimum height=3em},node distance=2em]
        \node (n0){Start};
        \node[block=28em,high,below=of n0] (n1){Identification Goal Definition + Prior Knowledge Accumulation};
        \node[block,below=of n1.south west,xshift=2em,anchor=north west] (n2){System Excitation};
        \node[block,below=of n2] (n3){Model Architecture Selection};
        \node[block,below=of n3] (n4){Order and Parameter Estimation};
        \node[block,below=of n4] (n5){Model Validation};
        \node[block=25em,high,below=of n5.south west,anchor=north west] (n6){Successful System Identification};

        \draw[-stealth] (n0) edge (n1)
        foreach \X in {1,...,5} {(n\X.south-|n2) edge (n\the\numexpr\X+1\relax.north-|n2)}
        (n5.east) -- ++(5em,0) coordinate (aux) |- (n2);
        \draw[-stealth] (aux|-n4) edge (n4) (n5.east) --++ (2em,0);
        \draw[-stealth] (aux|-n3) edge (n3) (n5.east) --++ (2em,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! There are on the order 100 such diagrams on this site. Now there is one more of them. In order to accomplish proper positioning, you may want to use the `positioning` library. There are many other tools such as `chains` but in this case they do not pay off IMHO.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw,minimum width=#1,minimum height=2em},
 block/.default=10em,high/.style={minimum height=3em},node distance=2em]
 \node (n0){Start};
 \node[block=28em,high,below=of n0] (n1){};
 \node[block,below=of n1.south west,xshift=2em,anchor=north west] (n2){};
 \node[block,below=of n2] (n3){};
 \node[block,below=of n3] (n4){};
 \node[block=25em,high,below=of n4.south west,anchor=north west] (n5){};
 \draw[-stealth] (n0) edge (n1)
 foreach \X in {1,...,4} {(n\X.south-|n2) edge (n\the\numexpr\X+1\relax.north-|n2)}
 (n4.east) -- ++(5em,0) coordinate (aux) |- (n2);
 \draw[-stealth] (aux|-n3) edge (n3) (n4.east) --++ (2em,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to add arrows, you can use `quotes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw,minimum width=#1,minimum height=2em},
 block/.default=10em,high/.style={minimum height=3em},node distance=2em,auto]
 \node (n0){Start};
 \node[block=28em,high,below=of n0] (n1){};
 \node[block,below=of n1.south west,xshift=2em,anchor=north west] (n2){};
 \node[block,below=of n2] (n3){};
 \node[block,below=of n3] (n4){};
 \node[block=25em,high,below=of n4.south west,anchor=north west] (n5){};
 \draw[-stealth] (n0) edge["a"] (n1)
 foreach \X in {1,...,4} {(n\X.south-|n2) edge["b"] (n\the\numexpr\X+1\relax.north-|n2)}
 (n4.east) -- ++(5em,0) coordinate (aux) |- node[pos=0.75]{c}(n2);
 \draw[-stealth] (aux|-n3) edge["d"] (n3) (n4.east) --node{e}++  (2em,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is the code of your updated question with arrow texts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [block/.style={draw,minimum width=#1,minimum height=2em},
        block/.default=10em,high/.style={minimum height=3em},
        node distance=2em,auto]
        \node (n0){Start};
        \node[block=28em,high,below=of n0] (n1){Identification Goal Definition + Prior Knowledge Accumulation};
        \node[block,below=of n1.south west,xshift=2em,anchor=north west] (n2){System Excitation};
        \node[block,below=of n2] (n3){Model Architecture Selection};
        \node[block,below=of n3] (n4){Order and Parameter Estimation};
        \node[block,below=of n4] (n5){Model Validation};
        \node[block=25em,high,below=of n5.south west,anchor=north west] (n6){Successful System Identification};

        \draw[-stealth] (n0) edge["a"] (n1)
        foreach \Y [count=\X] in {bla,blub,pft,ghh,trf} 
        {(n\X.south-|n2) edge["\Y"] (n\the\numexpr\X+1\relax.north-|n2)}
        (n5.east) --  ++(5em,0) coordinate (aux) |- node[pos=0.75] {d} (n2) ;
        \draw[-stealth] (aux|-n3) edge["c"] (n3)
         (aux|-n4) edge["b"] (n4) (n5.east) -- node[pos=0.5]
        {prt} ++ (2em,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The texts are unique so that you can replace them by whatever you want. Please make sure to load the `quotes` library (and of course `positioning`) if you just add the `tikzpicture` to your document.

Comment: Thank you both ! That was exactly what I needed and I understand the code ;) Could you additionally tell me how to put text over the arrows ? That would be quite it !

Comment: @aladin I added some texts. If you want to have different texts over the arrows done in the `\foreach` loop you either need to break up the loop or add some array.

Comment: I have added my solution :) I added another box but fail at getting text on it. Your code compiles fine whereas my does not when I apply the same ["a"] for example. Any idea ? Thank you !

Comment: @aladin I added texts to the arrows of the code that you added to your question.

Comment: Thank you ! That is so nice, I was on the right way by myself but however got this problem (btw I'm using overleaf). When I try to copy just the tikzpicture (i am loading quotes and positioning in the preamble), I get this error:

Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"bla" ' etc.

Comment: @aladin Do you load the babel package? If so, add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to the preamble. If this does not help, post a question with a complete document, i.e. starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{documents}`. It is very hard to debug an error that one does not get.

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed, it was the babel package that I did not include ... Thank you very much, you really helped me !

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of @Schrödinger's cat answer. With use of `chains` library and macro `join:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains, 
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 8mm and 0mm,
      start chain = going above,
       box/.style = {draw, minimum width=#1, minimum height=12mm, on chain},
     box/.default = 44mm,
every join/.style = {<-},
                > = {Stealth[length=3mm]}
                        ]
\node (n1) [box=88mm]{};
\node (n2) [box, above right=of n1.north west] {};
\node (n3) [box,join] {};
\node (n4) [box,join] {};
\node (n5) [box=96mm, above right=8mm and -8mm of n4.north west] {};
\draw[<-]  (n5.north) -- ++ (0,0.8) node[above] {Start};
%
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style={->}]
\draw  (n5.south -| n4) -- (n4);
\draw  (n2.east) -- ++ (1,0);
\draw  (n2.east) ++ (1,0) -- ++ (1,0) |- (n3);
\draw  (n3.east) ++ (2,0) |- (n4);
\draw  (n2) -- (n2 |- n1.north);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]